# Spring MVC - What is responsible for routing the controller response to the template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I started developing a Spring MVC + Thymeleaf (for the V) recently and I'm trying to understand how it works.

Let's say I have a controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index() {
    return "home";
}
```

And a template called home.html.

What is reponsible for routing the controller to the respective view? Is it thymeleaf? Or the Spring framework?

Thank you

Comment: I am not agree with Rayan M. Please go through this link which describe the [Views and View Resolvers in Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring's `ViewResolver`(s) do this: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html

Which view resolver(s) are active and where they look for templates is customizable based on your individual Spring configuration.